# How can I enforce persistent ACLs on startup for /dev/video* devices?

Tags: access-control-list, ubuntu-18.04

I have a USB webcam on `/dev/video0` that I'm trying to access *before* a user logs in (to be precise, I have an Azure IoT Edge container running on an Ubuntu 18.04 instance that needs to run in headless mode, and the box needs to be able to be power cycled without someone having to physically log in every time).

If I **first** physically log in on the box, the ACLs are set properly for `/dev/video0`, and my container (which runs under `myuser`) can happily access `/dev/video0`:

```
myuser@myuser-UBUNTU:~$ sudo getfacl /dev/video0
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/video0
# owner: root
# group: video
user::rw-
user:myuser:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

But if I do not physically log in on the box (e.g. right after a reboot), my user's account (`myuser`) never gets ACL access to `/dev/video0` (instead, the `gdm` user gets it).

```
myuser@myuser-UBUNTU:~$ sudo getfacl /dev/video0
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/video0
# owner: root
# group: video
user::rw-
user:gdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

I'm 99% sure this is an ACL problem, because when I ssh into the box (*before* physically logging in), and manually add `myuser` to the ACL list for `/dev/video0`, my container can again happily access `/dev/video0`.

**My question:** how can I ensure that on startup, when `/dev/video0` is mounted, that this automatically happens:

```
sudo setfacl -m u:myuser:rw /dev/video0
```

Adding **myuser** to the *video* group **does not work** (ACLs seem broken on Ubuntu in this respect):

```
sudo usermod -a -G video myuser
```

I've tried every variation I can possibly think of RE: groups, with no impact. It seems like I really need to automatically add `myuser` to the ACL for `/dev/video0` when Ubuntu starts, but I am unsure how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be extremely precise, you need to start this before Docker starts your container.

So you can add a drop-in for the Docker systemd unit, to run whatever you wish prior to Docker starting.

For instance, I would create a systemd drop-in like this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/video-permissions.conf <<EOF
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/setfacl -m u:myuser:rw /dev/video0
EOF
```

At this point, whenever Docker starts, the indicated command will be run beforehand.